# how to make unit tests of this error handler function?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, testing, jasmine

This function is handling error of HTTP requests, it catching error from client-side and server-side, I want to know how to test both errors.

```
  handleError(error: any): any {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Get client-side error
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      // Get server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

This is an example of the function that I'm using to get Data from services by request, also this function is handling errors from other functions that make requests by GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

```
  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://example.com')
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: You should test  scenarios 1) error is an instance of `ErrorEvent` . 2) error is not an instance of `ErrorEvent` 3) change `errorMessage` type, make it `int` or something  and then  test `throwError` 4) pass null in `error`  5) pass null in `errorMessage`

Comment: @user1207289 I'm trying to do what you said but I think I'm not understanding, I'm passing a number to `error` and I'm having a server-side error but when I'm sending a null for `error` and I'm getting this in the test `TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null`. Can you write the unit test? Thank you

Comment: You can modify question with the information you provided . Include what you have tried and explain, so anyone here can understand what you are looking for. This way you have better chances of an answer